# How to reuse existing mapper when mapping target uses Inheritance

Tags: java, mapping, mapstruct

I have `Inventory` class and `InventoryResponse` class.

```
public class Inventory {
  private InventoryStatus inventoryStatus;
}

public class InventoryResponse {
  private string inventoryStatus;    
}
```

I am able to create the mapping from Inventory to InventoryResponse  using a mapper.

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)

public abstract class InventoryResponseMapper {

  @Mapping(source = "inventoryStatus.inventoryStatusCd", target = "inventoryStatus")
  public abstract InventoryResponse toInventoryResponse(Inventory inventory);

}
```

Now, I have a new version of response, `InventoryResponseV1`, which has an additional property called `inventoryId`. To re-use, I have extended `InventoryResponse` class.

```
public class InventoryResponseV1 extends InventoryResponse {
   private String inventoryId;
}
```

Now, to map `Inventory` to `InventoryResponseV1`, I wanted to re-use `InventoryResponseMapper` class, by using, `uses = {InventoryResponseMapper.class}`

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE, uses = {InventoryResponseMapper.class})

public interface InventoryResponseV1Mapper {
    @Mapping(target = "inventoryId", expression = "java(java.util.UUID.randomUUID())")
    InventoryResponseV1 toInventoryResponseV1(Inventory inventory);
}
```

My expectation, all existing mapping from Inventory to InventoryResponseV1 will be resolved using InventoryResponseMapper (InventoryResponseV1 is InventoryResponse).

How ever the mapping fails with following error:

> error: Can't map property "com.myOrg.InventoryStatus inventoryStatus" to "java.lang.String inventoryStatus". Consider to declare/implement a mapping method: "java.lang.String map(com.myOrg.InventoryStatus value)".
> InventoryResponseV1 toInventoryResponseV1(Inventory product);

Is this expectation incorrect, taking [mapstruct](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/) into account? I have also tried using [@DecoratedWith](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#customizing-mappers-using-decorators), but realized it has a different use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to reuse configuration like this you need to use `MapperConfig`.

So in your use case you can do something like:

```
@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE, config = InventoryResponseMapper.class)
public interface InventoryResponseV1Mapper {

    @Mapping(target = "inventoryId", expression = "java(java.util.UUID.randomUUID())")
    @InheritConfiguration
    InventoryResponseV1 toInventoryResponseV1(Inventory inventory);

}
```

and you can make your other mapper a configuration as well

e.g.

```
@MapperConfig
@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
public abstract class InventoryResponseMapper {

  @Mapping(source = "inventoryStatus.inventoryStatusCd", target = "inventoryStatus")
  public abstract InventoryResponse toInventoryResponse(Inventory inventory);

}
```